# Create Geospatial PDF (GeoPDF) is greyed out in PDF export options in QGIS 3.10

Tags: qgis, gdal, export, geospatial-pdf, geopdf

I installed QGIS 3.10 standalone version today and I know it has a new feature introduced in this version to export GeoPDF. But for some reason, it is greyed out.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The QGIS and GRASS team is busy preparing a new build with GDAL/OGR 3.x support. It will be available soon (some days max). Please be patient until then.

Comment: Thank you for the update.

Comment: Available! (version released the 12th november 2019)

Comment: Is this new version available for Mac?

Answer (score 13):

For clarity
(Windows 10)

Download the OSGeo4W (64 bit)
https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html

Install as **Advanced Install**

[image]

Change the default GDAL to 3.1.0.137

[image]

Then in QGIS you should get the option for Exporting to **Geo-PDF**

[image]

Hopefully soon (when GDAL/GRASS is updated) this becomes the default in the QGIS install.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to work around this on Mac?

Comment: @neal ask a new question please.

Comment: mac-specific question posted at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345761/export-geospatial-pdf-from-qgis-on-mac

Answer (score 6):

the official release qgis 3.10 is compiled against gdal 2.41, therefore this option is not available. if you need this feature at the moment there is a workaround use the OSGeo4W networkinstaller and activate the gdaldev option

please see this tweed https://twitter.com/mapperz/status/1188607950824206336?s=20