# GeoPDF export in QGIS requires GDAL 3, how do I get GDAL 3?

Tags: qgis, osx

I would like to use the new GeoPDF export feature of QGIS 3.10. The [changelog](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/visualchangelog310/#feature-geopdf-export) states that it requires GDAL 3. I have QGIS 3.10 installed on OS X from the binary installer. The export GeoPDF feature is unavailable to me because GDAL 2 is enclosed in the program. Under about QGIS I find this:

Compiled against GDAL/OGR 2.4.1
Running against GDAL/OGR 2.4.1

Here are my questions:

1. Am I right in my assumption that I cannot 'just' install GDAL 3 to solve this issue, but need to compile QGIS from source against GDAL 3?
2. If assumption 1 is incorrect: how can install GDAL 3 to use the GeoPDF function?
3. If assumption 1 is correct: are precompiled installers available with GDAL 3?

I would be surprised if an end-user feature like this would require the program to be self-compiled.

Edit: this question is similar to [this one for Windows](http://Create%20Geospatial%20PDF%20(GeoPDF)%20is%20greyed%20out%20in%20PDF%20export%20options%20in%20QGIS%203.10) however, for Windows an advanced installer is available. For OS X it is not.

For now I will:

1. Try QGIS on Linux (don't have Windows).
2. Inform on the development of the Mac version or add feature request.
3. Hope I can have this feature on the Mac soon as well.

If all fails I'll borrow a PC with ArcMap.

Comment: Seems like there is an "advanced installer" for other operating systems where you can choose which GDAL to be used. In the Mac install it's just a drag and drop...

Comment: I think you are right! reading your comment I noticed a related question which shows the procedure. Had I found it before I wouldn't have posted the question. Conclusion: I'm going to install linux. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340030/create-geospatial-pdf-geopdf-is-greyed-out-in-pdf-export-options-in-qgis-3-10

Comment: I guess you could file a bug report / feature request for Mac on their Github: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Geospatial PDF (GeoPDF) is greyed out in PDF export options in QGIS 3.10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340030/create-geospatial-pdf-geopdf-is-greyed-out-in-pdf-export-options-in-qgis-3-10)

Comment: QGIS will need to be re-package with the changes "Rebuilds of QGIS 3.10.0, QGIS 3.4.13 and spatialite 4.3.0a against the above
  packages"   https://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/grass-user/2019-November/080973.html

Comment: @nmtoken this question states OSX (I have no apple macs to test on) the duplicate is for Windows Installers (but the underlying issue is being fixed for all Operating Systems for GeoPDF Export in QGIS 3.10+)