# Export geospatial PDF from QGIS on Mac

Tags: qgis, gdal, geopdf

I am trying to take advantage of the new georeferenced PDF export in QGIS 3.10 but the checkbox is grayed out with a message that "GeoPDF creation required GDAL version 3.0 or later".

The answers from [Create Geospatial PDF (GeoPDF) is greyed out in PDF export options in QGIS 3.10](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/340030) include a workaround for windows as well as claims that the newest releases and nightly builds are now built against GDAL 3.  However, I downloaded the mac nightly from [here](https://qgis.org/downloads/macos/qgis-macos-nightly.dmg) and it still uses GDAL 2.4.1.

Can anyone tell me how to get the necessary versions on a Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[QGIS 3.16 on macOS](https://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/blog/2020/10/01/qgis-macos-package/) comes with GDAL 3.1.2 in which you can use to export geospatial PDF.

[image]

I don't have macOS to test it, but based on reports provided by many users that QGIS 3.10 does not support GDAL 3, the above link shows clearly that it is now supported in QGIS 3.16. Therefore, it is better to upgrade to the latest version of [QGIS 3.16](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html#) to get geospatial PDF export feature.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It looks like the version of GDAL that is bundled with QGIS will be updated soon.

In the meantime, I was able to export to GeoPDF by exporting to GeoTIFF (make sure you check the box "include world file", and then using the raster Translate (Convert Format) tool to export to PDF. Note: An error saying the layers were incorrectly generated may pop up, but your PDF should still export, and you should be able to use it as a georeferenced image in Avenza or other programs.

I hope this works, and fingers crossed that the broader issue is solved quickly, see here for updates: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/32511