# Export map from QGIS as georeferenced map to be used in Avenza Maps

Tags: qgis, google-maps, georeferencing, mac, avenza

I am familiar with ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro, but I am extremely green when it comes to QGIS.  The version I am using is QGIS 3.10.2 on macOS High Sierra 10.13.6.  I have created a map using Google Maps satellite imagery for forest inventory purposes. Now I wish to export it as a georeferenced map to be used on Avenza Maps.  When I go to export the map, the GeoPDF option is greyed out.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a better way to go about it?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [Mapperz](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357870/how-to-export-a-map-from-qgis-3-10-2-as-a-georeferenced-map-to-be-used-in-avenza#comment585545_357870) hit the nail on the head.

> ["GeoPDF creation required GDAL version 3.0 or later"](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345761/export-geospatial-pdf-from-qgis-on-mac)

On QGIS for macOS, it doesn't come with GDAL and you need GDAL in order to create geospatial PDFs.

Check that you have GDAL on with your QGIS 3.10.2 build. If you do have GDAL, make sure that you are checking off "Create Geospatial PDF" in the export options.