# Export GeoPDF Mac

Tags: qgis, mac, geopdf

I want to export a georeferenced PDF from my QGIS project, and I am unable to tick the box as I need GDAL 3.0. However, my colleague is using windows (I am using a mac) and he is able to export as a GeoPDF without any issue, despite him not having GDAL. How can I generate a solution?

I know this question seems to have been asked before, however these questions are related to GDAL. I am not sure why I need GDAL at all, since I know my colleague on Windows doesn't have it (and I tried to install it via homebrew and it didn't work

Edit - I installed QQIS from Qgis.org. I have both 3.10 and 3.12 installed. I am running 10.14.6 (Mojave).

Comment: Have a read here also. [https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345761/export-geospatial-pdf-from-qgis-on-mac](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345761/export-geospatial-pdf-from-qgis-on-mac)