# Why is 'Create Geospatial PDF.' greyed out?

Tags: qgis, gdal, geospatial-pdf

I am using QGIS to create a map that can be used in avenza. When I try to export as a PDF it does not allow me to tick the box of Create geospatial PDF. I am using Mac Catalina and the current version of QGIS is 3.14.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370540/why-cant-i-make-geospatialpdfs-using-qgis-3-14

Comment: Can you provide some pictures and what type of data you are using?