# Option to save as GeoPDF greyed out 3.14.16 MacOS Catalina

Tags: qgis-3, geopdf, macos

I've been looking through post asking the same question but can't get it work.
This post [Why can't I make GeospatialPDFs using QGIS 3.14?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370540/why-cant-i-make-geospatialpdfs-using-qgis-3-14?noredirect=1&lq=1) mentioned a "PDF driver there for creating Geospatial PDF's" under Preferences > Options > GDAL but I can't located it.
I have the exact same about screen as in the post.

Has this issue been solved yet?

Comment: I believe it is to do with the version of GDAL, it needs to be 3.0+ but the macOS version is on 2.4.1? [I don't have a Mac to test on].  see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/345761/export-geospatial-pdf-from-qgis-on-mac

Comment: Indeed, even with regal 3.0+ installed (an checked form he terminal) QGIS still recognises only version 2.4...